# Create - Azure Virtual Machine Windows

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

When we create a VM from Azure new portal, in the settings blade we can select the Virtual Network, Subnet, IPAddress and Soon... else Azure will create by default saying (new).

[image]

But my subscription is not populating the (new), its mandating me to create each is there any setting which restrict this.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, I'm not able to tell what your actual question is. Please clarify.

Comment: Do you create VMs in the resource group? Could you try to use another browser?

Answer (score 0):

I find you asked question on this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31a839b1-04a0-48ef-8bd7-2cc5a501a25f/default-settings-in-azure-vm-blade-are-not-loading?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).

According to your screenshot, it seems a browser issue. Azure does not have the limit. You could try to use another browsers, such as IE, chrome or try to reset your browsers and try again.